# Python: Get data BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need help with BeautifulSoup, I'm trying to get the data:

`<font face="arial" font-size="16px" color="navy">001970000521</font>`

They are many and I need to get the value inside "font"

```
<div id="accounts" class="elementoOculto">
            <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing=0 width="90%">         <tr><th align="left" colspan=2>                 permisos            </th></tr><tr>
    <td colspan=2>
        <table width=100% align=center border=0 cellspacing=1>
            <tr>
                <th align=center width="20%">cuen</th>
                <th align=center>Mods</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<table align="center" border="0" cellspacing=1 width="90%">
    <tr bgcolor="whitesmoke" height="08">
        <td align="left" width="20%">
            <font face="arial" font-size="16px" color="navy">001970000521</font>
        </td>
        <td>......

 <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing=1 width="90%">
        <tr bgcolor="whitesmoke" height="08">
            <td align="left" width="20%">
                <font face="arial" font-size="16px" color="navy">001970000521</font>
            </td>
```

I hope you can help me, thanks.

Comment: Can you document what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `bs4.Tag.find_all` method or something similar.

```
soup.find_all(attrs={"face":"arial","font-size":"16px","color":"navy"})
```

Example:

```
>>>import bs4 
>>>html='''<div id="accounts" class="elementoOculto">             <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing=0 width="90%">         <tr><th align="left" colspan=2>                 permisos            </th></tr><tr>     <td colspan=2>         <table width=100% align=center border=0 cellspacing=1>             <tr>                 <th align=center width="20%">cuen</th>                 <th align=center>Mods</th>             </tr>         </table>     </td> </tr> </table> <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing=1 width="90%">     <tr bgcolor="whitesmoke" height="08">         <td align="left" width="20%">             <font face="arial" font-size="16px" color="navy">001970000521</font>         </td>         <td>......   <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing=1 width="90%">         <tr bgcolor="whitesmoke" height="08">             <td align="left" width="20%">                 <font face="arial" font-size="16px" color="navy">001970000521</font>             </td> '''
>>>print bs4.BeautifulSoup(html).find_all(attrs={"face":"arial","font-size":"16px","color":"navy"})
 [<font color="navy" face="arial" font-size="16px">001970000521</font>, <font color="navy" face="arial" font-size="16px">001970000521</font>]
```

Comment: i get 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'

Answer (score 1):

how about this?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
str = '''<div id="accounts" class="elementoOculto">
            <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing=0 width="90%">         <tr><th align="left" colspan=2>                 permisos            </th></tr><tr>
    <td colspan=2>
        <table width=100% align=center border=0 cellspacing=1>
            <tr>
                <th align=center width="20%">cuen</th>
                <th align=center>Mods</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<table align="center" border="0" cellspacing=1 width="90%">
    <tr bgcolor="whitesmoke" height="08">
        <td align="left" width="20%">
            <font face="arial" font-size="16px" color="navy">001970000521</font>
        </td>
        <td>......

 <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing=1 width="90%">
        <tr bgcolor="whitesmoke" height="08">
            <td align="left" width="20%">
                <font face="arial" font-size="16px" color="navy">001970000521</font>
            </td>'''

bs = BeautifulSoup(str)
print bs.font.string
```

Comment: i get 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'

Comment: What version of python did you use?

Comment: Sorry, the error is when I get the soup, "bs = BeautifulSoup (str)" in html only me is keeping a piece of code and ends with </ html> before you start the part of the code I'm looking for.

As I can do to get where the other begins html tag?

Comment: I don't understand your question, sorry ((

Comment: Sorry my english, im from Venezuela.. example:

Comment: <html>test</html><html>test2</html> all code in one var and beautifulsoup take: <html>test</html>

Comment: I think that BS4 will not help you with so wrong html. But regexp will

Comment: we now discussing different question. Task from this question is solved, if you make a new question and define problems I will try to help.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) starting from the `div` with `id="accounts"`:

```
soup.select("div#accounts table > tr > font")
```